# How to avoid Hgap for first component added to a JPanel using FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout

In my software i have a JPanel containing some JComponent. The JPanel use a FlowLayout with a certain Hgap to separate these components.

[image: Example Software Image]

I'm trying to have this kind of design, but the first component should be layed out on left, without any Hgap. Like This:

[image: Example Software Wanted]

here is the code you can use to generate the example:

```
public class FlowLayoutExample {

    public static void main(String [] a) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 80));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(350, 80));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setContentPane(initJPanel());

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
   }

    private static JPanel initJPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
        flowLayout.setHgap(25);
        panel.setLayout(flowLayout);
        panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        panel.add(initLabel());
        panel.add(initLabel());
        panel.add(initLabel());
        panel.add(initLabel());
        return panel;
    }

    private static Component initLabel() {
        return new JLabel("MyLabel");
    }

}
```

Thanks for any suggestion you'll leave !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `EmptyBorder` to fake it out:

```
panel.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(0, -25, 0, 0) );
```

Basically the border inset and layout gap are added together.

Comment: Thanks for the work-around, it works properly.
If noone find a batter way to manage it,  i'll check this answer as good.

Comment: `If noone find a batter way to manage it,` - this is how you would do it using a FlowLayout. You can always use other layout managers, like a `BoxLayout` or `GridBagLayout` but then you have to manage the constraints yourself with the GridBagLayout or add extra components for the spacing with the BoxLayout.

Comment: i tried with both. But BoxLayout and GridBagLayout stretching behave are not good for my purpose, and i don't want to use the migLayout. I think i ll go with the negative left empty border

Comment: BoxLayout and GridBagLayout will NOT stretch a JLabel, so your code is wrong. As I suggested it is extra work to use either of those layouts. In any case the problem was solved days ago and the answer should be "accepted" so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: i didn't say they stretch a jlabel, i said the stretchin behave is not good for my purpose. In other words, those jlabels are contained in a jpanel which cannot be layed out with something that stretches

Comment: And I said, a BoxLayout will not stretch, neither will GridBagLayout if you use the proper constraints. That is whether you use FlowLayout, BoxLayout or GridBagLayout you can have the components displayed at their preferred size so they don't stretch even as extra space is allocated to the panel.